# Retrieving image from sql database by its path

Tags: asp.net

I have a database where i have the physical path where image of a person is stored .
now i want a code by which I can display the image of that person in a aspx window.

as I am new to asp.net & C# 
can somebody provide me the full code of aspx page and the C# code behind it?

Comment: Click the accepted answer icon below the votebuttons on the answer that solved your problem.
The user who provided the answer will get points and the answer will appear at the top.

Comment: now can i have solution to this problem?

Comment: Your question is both very broad and very easy: Did you try anything yourself at all? Questions of this "Show me te codez" type usually don't get a lot of answers.

Comment: I agree with @Jakob, What have you tried yourself? Where are you coming unstuck? What does your database schema look like? Are you limited by any technologies (.NET 2?, 3?, 3.5) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good example on how to connect to a database and display the data in ASP.NET: [How to: Bind to Data in a Templated Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95k0273d.aspx) on MSDN.
Also there a lots of great tutorials on the [ASP.NET](http://asp.net) "official" site.

Update:
Alright, now we got something to work with. Do you know if your HttpHandler is throwing any exceptions? Place a breakpoint in the HttpHandler code and hit F5 (Visual Studio) to launch the site in debug bug mode. Maybe you're not passing an image ID to the handler? Try and hardcode an ID in the .aspx for an image you know that exists in the database.

See if you can update your question and format the code: Just select the code sample and click the "code" button in the editor. It will indent the text and apply nice formatting, making it easier to read. 
Also include your .aspx page so we can see what's going on there.

Comment: help me by the above context plzz.